# Unsatisfied dependencies for type X at injection point besides bean-discovery-mode set to "all"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa, wildfly, cdi

I am running Jakarta EE 9 (Java JDK 17) project on Wildfly 27.0.1 Final that alsp uses Spring-data. I had a similar setup running on Java EE 8 (Java SDK 8) on Wildfly 20.0.1 Final running without issues.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ProjectName</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ProjectName</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.ejb/jakarta.ejb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.11.23.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.23.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

To make it work I added a class called CdiConfig to make EntityManager available where it's needed:

```
public class CdiConfig {

    @Produces
    @Dependent
    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager entityManager;
    
}
```

And, also I made sure that my repository initiates eagerly:

```
@Eager
public interface GameRepository extends CrudRepository<Game, Long> {
    Game findByUniqueId(String uniqueId);
}
```

And, then finally from the facade I try to inject the repository:

```
@Stateless
public class GameFacade {

    @Inject
    GameRepository repository;
...
```

I also added beans.xml to /webapp/WEB-INF/ to make the repository discoverable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
        https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

However,

I still get

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type GameRepository with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.example.project.facade.GameFacade.repository
  at com.example.project.facade.GameFacade.repository(GameFacade.java:0)
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing spring data jpa version to 3.0.1 everything seems to work